# Discord.py: How would I get the input from the user after they use a command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a higher lower game in my bot but I can't figure out how to get the user's input after they enter in the command to start the game. How would I do this?

```
@client.command(aliases=['highlow'])
async def higherlower(ctx):
    random_number = randint(1, 25)
    guess = 0
    tries = 5

    # code here that detects user input

    while guess != random_number:
        if tries == 0:
            await ctx.send('You're out of tries! Try again.)
            break
        if guess != random_number:
            tries = tries -1
            await ctx.send('Incorrect!' + tries + ' tries left.')
        if guess == random_number:
            await ctx.send('You got it! The number was ' + random_number)
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you need to use the `while True` and `client.wait_for` parts of discord.py:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['highlow'])
async def higherlower(ctx):
    random_number = randint(1, 25)
    tries = 5

    while True:
        guess_message = await client.wait_for('message')

        if guess_message.author == ctx.message.author:
            guess = int(guess_message.content)
            if tries == 0:
                await ctx.send('You're out of tries! Try again.)
                break
            if guess != random_number:
                tries = tries -1
                await ctx.send('Incorrect!' + tries + ' tries left.')
            if guess == random_number:
                await ctx.send('You got it! The number was ' + random_number)
                break
```

Comment: flags an error: if guess_message.author == ctx.message.author: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'author'

Comment: I edited it. It should've been `guess_message = await client.wait_for('message')`. I forgot the `await`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

(Make a new function that initializes the global variables, while the "higherlower" function is reserved for guessing)

```
random_number = 0
guess = 0
tries = 0

@client.command()
async def start_higherlower(ctx):
    global random_number, guess, tries

    random_number = randint(1, 25)
    guess = 0
    tries = 5

@client.command(aliases=['highlow'])
async def higherlower(ctx):
    global random_number, guess, tries

    if tries == 0:
        await ctx.send('You're out of tries! Try again.)
        #End_higherlower()
    elif guess == random_number:
        await ctx.send('You got it! The number was ' + random_number)
        #End_higherlower()
    else:
        tries = tries -1
        await ctx.send('Incorrect!' + tries + ' tries left.')
```

Comment: Wouldn't that require you to re enter the command every single time you guess? What if you call higherlow when you haven't already run start_higherlower?

I appreciate the response but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to get the user input after you enter the command, but using the same command. In the comments in the code I posted, it says an example area of where you'd ask for their guess.